# Java.lang.classcastException javax.naming.reference cannot cast to Jakarta.jms

Tags: java, spring-boot, ibm-mq, java-17

[image]Getting the error when upgrading spring boot to latest version

```
   Class javax.naming.reference cannot be cast to Jakarta.jms.QueueConnectionFactory (javax.naming.reference is in module java.naming of loader ‘bootstrap’; Jakarta.jms.QueueConnectionFactory is in unnamed module of loader ‘app’
```

```
code snippets 
We’re upgrading to spring boot 3.0.6. We are using ibm mq and updated mq-jms-spring-boot-starter to 3.1.0.

While creating the QueueConnectionFactory getting above exception
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: Can you add more details?

Comment: Are you trying to mix and match JMS 2.0 and JMS 3.0? Jakarta and pre-Jakarta? Show us your code - import statements at least.

Comment: import Jakarta.jms.*.        iImport javax.naming.IntialContext; import javax.namingzJmsExcepton; Import Javax.naming.Context;

Comment: @MoragHughson added the imports and code snippets

Comment: Please don't add code as iamges, add them as code (text with code tags for readability).

Answer (score 0):

You really need to share code, as it would make it easier to diagnose what is going on, but based on the tags.

I am guessing that you are using `Spring Boot` and maybe `Spring JMS`, and you have a `@Autowired` reference to an `ConnectionFactory`.

The cause will be because you have made a mistake in your dependencies. Most likely the version of `com.ibm.mq` latest version of which is at `3.1.2`

```
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>mq-jms-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
```

After seeing your code, I'm appending to this answer.

By using Spring JMS in conjunction with the `mq-jms-spring-boot-starter` means that you don't need to dabble with JNDI, it's done for you. You only need to populate `application.properties` with the appropriate property settings.

There is a repository of [samples](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-patterns/tree/master/Spring-JMS) that will help get you kick started.

More details on usage and available properties are documented in the [MQ Spring Boot starter GitHub repository](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-jms-spring).

The likelihood is that you may not even need to refer to the ConnectionFactory, unless you are deviating from the default settings, in which case all you will need is

```
    @Autowired
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
```

The JDNI stuff is done for you.

Comment: I’m using spring boot 3.X and upgraded mq-jms-spring-boot-starter to 3.1.0. In this starter  jar it has com.ibm.mq.Jakarta.client:9.3.2.1.I’ve not added any other dependencies.

Comment: Added the code snippet

Comment: added the code snippet and imports